# python script to export csv file - not imported correctly on tablepress

Tags: python, excel, csv

I tried to solve this problem, but it's just not working. The code exports a .csv file that can be viewed fine in excel (but it skips a line every line..), but when i upload to tablepress or websimontables the code puts all of the rows in one cell instead of each in their own cell resulting in a table that looks off.

You can see an example of what i'm talking about here http://www.dustindavisyourrealtor.com/2015/08/06/85/.  The top table is output from this script, the bottom table is an example of what i'm looking for.

Here is the link to the input .csv file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/figher1vgnlmwju/realtor.csv?dl=0

To run the script: python conv.py input.csv output.csv

```
import sys
import re
import csv
import urllib

CHARS_TO_REMOVE = (
    0xa0, 0xae
)
RE1 = re.compile('^\d+$')
RE2 = re.compile('^\w{3}\s\d+\/\d+$')
FLAG1 = 'f1'
FLAG2 = 'f2'
URL_BASE = 'https://www.instantstreetview.com/s/%s'
EMAIL_LINK = '<a href=\'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=email@here.ca%20&su=Hello%20again\'>I want more information about this house</a>'


def cleanLine(line):
    for ch in CHARS_TO_REMOVE:
        line = line.replace(chr(ch), '')
    return line.strip()

def checkRow(row):
    m1 = RE1.match(row[0])
    if m1:
        return FLAG1
    else:
        m2 = RE2.match(row[0])
        if m2:
            return FLAG2
    return None

def formatRow(row):
    Addr= ' '.join(row['row1'][5:8])
    Url = URL_BASE % urllib.quote_plus(Addr)
    Row = {
        #'Date' : row['row2'][0],
        #'Time' : row['row2'][1],
        'Date / Time' : ' '.join(row['row2'][0:2]),
        'Type' : row['row1'][1],
        'Beds' : row['row1'][2],
        'Bath' : row['row1'][3],
        'Address' : row['row1'][5] + ', ' + row['row1'][6],
        'Listed At' : row['row1'][4],
        'Area' : '<a href=\'%s\'>See the neighbourhood</a>' % Url,
        'Get In Touch!' : EMAIL_LINK
    }

    return Row

def main(fnameIn, fnameOut):

    Rows = []
    row1 = None
    row2 = None
    for row in csv.reader(file(fnameIn).readlines()):
        row = map(cleanLine, row)
        flag = checkRow(row)
        if flag == FLAG1:
            row1 = row
            row2 = None
        elif flag == FLAG2:
            row2 = row

        if row1 and row2:
            Rows.append(dict(row1=row1, row2=row2))
            row1 = row2 = None

    with open(fnameOut, 'w') as f:

        fieldnames = ['Date / Time', 'Type', 'Beds', 'Bath', 'Address', 'Listed At', 'Area', 'Get In Touch!']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        writer.writeheader()

        for row in Rows:
            writer.writerow(formatRow(row))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.arg[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: The link to your example is broken. Please post sample input too.

Comment: Ah, thanks for bringing that to my attention.  I'll add that to the main file and fix the broken link.

Comment: The output looks OK to me, and I have no problems importing it into libreoffice. Have you tried it without specifying `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` ?

Comment: I just tried it removing the "quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL" and still no change. The rows are double spaced, and all going into the first cell still. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Comment: I Fixed it.
I changed 
    with open(fnameOut, 'w') as f:
To with open(fnameOut, 'wb') as f:
It removed the blank lines and the wonky windows formatting (which i just learned about) and it imported correctly into tablepress.

Thanks for your help!